# When passing data from one class to another, should you pass the entire model, or separate arguments?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a model with quite a bit of parameters:

```
UserDataModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.phone,
    this.photo,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.birthday,
    this.sex,
    this.land,
    this.bio,
    this.interests,
    this.facebook,
    this.instagram,
    this.telegram,
    this.register,
    this.login,
    this.timezone,
    this.banned,
    this.bannedDate,
    this.locked,
    this.lockedDate,
    this.postsNum,
    this.likesNum,
    this.commentsNum,
    this.views,
    this.notifications,
    this.push,
    this.position,
    this.rating,
    this.rewards,
    this.verified,
    this.notify,
    this.the2Fa,
    this.params,
  });
```

and I'm using a stream to pass this model to a widget that only needs rating.level(a submodel for the `rating` parameter) and photo.small(another submodel, but for the `photo` parameter).

And I'm wondering if passing the entire model to a widget that only requires 2 parameters can lead to more memory being used, for example. It's not a big deal to do it either way, and it would be a bit upsetting to leave some minor optimisation on the table.

Any help is appreciated. I guess this question can apply to any language, but since I'm using flutter, I'll tag it with that.

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner to pass only what you need. If `rating.level` is an object, in your Flutter widget, add it as a requirement

```
Widget rating({required Level level})
```

In when you call this rating widget, pass the level only:

```
return rating(level: myUserModel.rating.level)
```

If this level is an `int` or `String` for example, do the same thing as well. I am not sure how significant this would impact performance, but the main reason for it is that this enables better widget reusability and recycling. Apply this to your other projects, when you have created a cool rating widget, but you have ratings for users, and for example products. Your `rating` model is the same, but the product and user data models are different.
Instead of having to create a model for ProductRating and UserRating, you can you the same `rating` widget, and this widget only requires the rating object, or level object.